# 3g modem/dongle inserted into a 3g router for remote access to a camera

Tags: networking, router

Does a 3g dongle have an IP address?

How do I ensure that the 3g dongle IP address does not conflict with the router IP address?

For some unknown reason DDNS works fine on my router for hours but then the DDNS just logs out.  Then I cannot remotely log into the router or the camera attached to it.  The local network works fine alright.

Usually I end up rebooting the router and everything works fine for another few hours until the DDNS stops functioning. I use dyndns.org and the settings there are fine.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. The router I use is a TP Link MR3420 v.2 with latest firmware installed.

Comment: Please clarify, does the DDNS client on the router crash, or does the hostname just stop resolving the right address? Is the 3G connection your only internet connection or is it a backup?

Comment: DDNS sometimes "not launching" on the router. Other times DDNS "succeeded" on the router but not showing correct ipaddress when I check   it on my account with dyndns.org. 3G connection is the only internet connection on the router.

Comment: There's a reasonably significant chance that you could be behind CGN when it comes to mobile internet. Does the router ever show 10. IPs for its public addrsess?

Comment: The ipaddress is a public one and I use the correct APN as provided by my ISP.